# Fetch params from URL using app controller

Tags: angularjs, url, controller

How to pass the multiple parameters to a function using this code? I am able to pass only Username as single parameter but MarkDate is not passing to URL.

```
 var app = angular.module("myModule", ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

    //This Gets all the Pre Clients
    app.controller("GetAttendance", function ($scope, $http) {
        window.params = function () {
            var params = {};
            var param_array = window.location.href.split('?')[1].split('&');
            for (var i in param_array) {
                x = param_array[i].split('=');
                params[x[0]] = x[1];
            }
            return params;
        } ();

        $http({
            url: "../assets/services/MasterWebService.asmx/spGetAttendanceByUsernameDate",
            method: "GET",
            **params: { Username: window.params.Username , MarkDate : params.Markdate}**
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.GetAttendanceData = response.data;
            $scope.TotalOrders = response.data.length;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "MarkDate" param is not getting its value from the `window.params` object as you do with "Username". This should work:

```
        $http({
            url: "../assets/services/MasterWebService.asmx/spGetAttendanceByUsernameDate",
            method: "GET",
            **params: { Username: window.params.Username , MarkDate : window.params.Markdate}**
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.GetAttendanceData = response.data;
            $scope.TotalOrders = response.data.length;
        });
```

Comment: But what is the mistake or error in My code , Everything looks to me same.

Comment: The `**params` object you use in the HTTP request is different. The value of `MarkDate` has to be `window.params.MarkDate` and in your code it is `params.markDate`

Comment: assets/services/MasterWebService.asmx/spGetAttendanceByUsernameDate?Username=1

But Still I am not receving MarkDate in url . Even after Changing to window.param.MarkDate.

Comment: Finally working now , there was an issue with URL Spelling